# OpenCart Redirect "Add To Cart" to Product Detail page

Tags: opencart2.x

I've changed "Add To Cart" button name to "View Detail" using language page. Now i want to change the link of "View Detail" button to product page instead of cart. When visitor click on the "View Detail" button they should be able to view product instead of adding product into cart.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove code from featured

```html
<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
```

and add

simple link like insted of about code

```html
<a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">View Detail</a>
```